# Passing a list loaded from text file to sql query in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, jdbc, apache-spark-sql

I have read accounts from a text file which use `,` as separator:

```
val csv = spark.read.text("src/main/resources/in/insight/account_issues.txt")

//implicits
import spark.sqlContext.implicits._

val string_account = csv.map(_.getString(0)).collect.toList.toString()
//print(string_account)

val query = s"""(SELECT
               |    ACCOUNT_NUMBER,
               |    CASE WHEN STMT.CRF_TYPE='CREDIT' THEN STMT.AMOUNT_LCY
               |        ELSE NULL
               |    END as 'CreditAmount',
               |    CASE WHEN STMT.CRF_TYPE='DEBIT' THEN STMT.AMOUNT_LCY
               |        ELSE  NULL
               |    END as 'DebitAmount',
               |    STMT.BOOKING_DATE,
               |    STMT.VALUE_DATE,
               |    CRF_TYPE
               |FROM [InsightLanding].[dbo].[v_STMT_ENTRY] AS STMT
               |    LEFT JOIN [InsightWarehouse].[dbo].[v_Account] AS A ON a.AccountNum = STMT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
               |
               |WHERE STMT.MIS_DATE='$BusinessDate'
               | AND STMT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER IN ($string_account) ) tmp """.stripMargin

val responseWithSelectedColumns = spark
  .read
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", url)
  .option("driver", driver)
  .option("dbtable", query)
  .load()
```

I cannot get the works instead getting error:

```
: 'List' is not a recognized built-in function name
```

What is wrong from my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create `string_account` you use `toString()` on a List. This will give you a string `List(...)`, for example:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).toString()
res0: String = List(1, 2, 3)
```

What you want to use instead is `mkString(",")`:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).mkString(",")
res1: String = "1,2,3"
```

In this case that would be:

```
val string_account = csv.map(_.getString(0)).collect.toList.mkString(",")
```

Note: You can add the parentheses easily to `string_account` instead of having them in the SQL query if wanted with `mkString("(", ",", ")")`.

Comment: do you mean I can change to this `val string_account = csv.map(_.getString(0)).collect.toList.mkString("(", ",", ")")`

Comment: @kn3l: I made the answer a bit clearer. If you don't change the SQL query, `val string_account = csv.map(_.getString(0)).collect.toList.mkString(",")` is correct.

Comment: my case ACCOUNT_NUMBER  is string data type like this
`ACCOUNT_NUMBER in ('14496084' ,'14038388' ,'12602537' ,'14497935' ,'11913927')`

Comment: @kn3l: I see, then you need to add `'` around each element. This can be done with `mkString` by adjusting it a bit: `mkString("'", "', '", "'")`. (The `(` and `)` is already in the sql query so no need to add here).